# Connection to oracle makes error when I use the jdbcTemplate in Spring

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have the following problem:

I use the jdbcTemplate to connect with the database with Spring.

When I run the program, I have the following error:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.8:1521:productdb'
```

My code is:

```
Connection con = jdbc.getDataSource().getConnection();

ArrayDescriptor desciptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
                    "string_array", con);
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace it will help us get a better understanding of the issue. Also check and make sure you have the correct Oracle jar on your class path.

Comment: Also check the syntax of you URL: 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/ServiceName 
or
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<SID>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="true"/>` in the confingure file.

```
  Connection dbConn = jdbc.getDataSource().getConnection();org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection del = new org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection(dbConn);
            Connection conn = del.getInnermostDelegate();
            ArrayDescriptor desciptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
                    "STRING_ARRAY",conn);
```